# unreported exception MalformedURLException when creating a URL

Tags: java

Excuse me for my lack of Java skills, but I am normally a C kind of person.. I am beginning some Android development and I want to simply make a GET request. However, I cannot even get a simple URL type to compile correctly. I keep getting this error:

```
HelloWorld.java:17: error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
 ^
1 error
```

When running this simple code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.io.Reader;
 import java.io.Writer;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.ProtocolException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLConnection;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");

        System.out.println(url.toString());
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Put your entire `URL url = ... ` thing in `Try-Catch` block.

Comment: Oh ok.. Does all java code require this?

Comment: @Matt Most of the time yes. Personally, I think Exceptions are terrible and cause code to look really ugly and can lead to bad design decisions

Comment: Java requires all exceptions (except RuntimeException and descendants) to be dealt with.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot guys.. I knew it was an obvious user-error :)

Comment: @PradeepSimha I think you mean checked exceptions. There is a reason they are called that.

Comment: I suggest that you use a good IDE (like Eclipse) to prevent automatically these sample errors..

Comment: @lory105 eclipse is a good IDE?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes I mean checked exception. I was working for long hours so maybe typo. ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For all checked exception, it becomes mandatory to handle them in your code. here are 2 ways to do that.

in general, 
you can either pass on the exception handling to caller of the declaring method using `throws` clause.
or you can handle them there itself using `try-catch[-finally]` construct.

in your case,
you either need to add `throws` clause to `main()` method as

`public static void main(String []args) throws MalformedURLException`{

or you need to surround URL declaration with `try-catch` block, like here:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
    //more code goes here
}catch(MalformedURLException ex){
//do exception handling here
}
```

Comment: I think you mean checked exceptions, so called as the compiler checks if you caught or explicitly declared those,  in contrast to the unchecked RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: Just as a side note (since the OP stated they're newish to Java) the throws exception goes on whatever method the code is in, and then must be caught or re-thrown by the parent method from which that method was called.  For example, if you did your URL declaration in the `setURL()` method, you could throw an exception on that method (`public void setURL() throws Exception {...`) then catch it where `setURL();` is called from, or you may re-throw the exception at that method level as well.  The biggest issue (that I know of) with throwing/re-throwing is that it makes bug finding more difficult.

Answer (score 6):

In java, you **must** handle exceptions.  The easiest way to do this in a sample program like this is to declare `main()` to throw:

```
public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
```

Go about your learning, and deal with exception handling issues later.

Comment: You only must handle checked exceptions.

Comment: OP is learning. Make it simple and the complexity will come later from use.

Comment: It is a really important distinction, especially if you're new to java. Better to learn it early

Answer (score 1):

Constructor of URL declares that it could throw an exception so you need to catch it or throw it back

---

**See**

- [Exception Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the url declaration within a try-catch (or throw it)

[Read more about exception handling.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
} catch(MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("The url is not well formed: " + url);
}
```

this is because creating an Url is "dangerous", and creating something like:

```
new URL("testurl");
```

will raise an exception.